# Python: Alternating Row Coloring in Outlook HTML Table

Tags: python, html, pandas, outlook, html-email

I have a Pandas DataFrame which I am sending as an HTML table through Microsoft Outlook. The problem is that the usual styling techniques used to add alternating row colouring do not work as Outlook does not support a bunch of HTML stuff.

I tried:

```
df.style.set_table_styles([{"selector":"tbody tr:nth-child(even)","props":[("background-color","lightgrey")]}])
```

Also tried:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: lightblue; }
```

However, both options arent working. Is there any way to add alternating row colors in an HTML table in Outlook?

Comment: Can't you add the background colour inline?

Comment: Well, I can. I was hoping there is a more elegant way...

Comment: Outlook does support basic styles like td class=x & .x {background-color...} but some email clients don't even support the `<style>` block (e.g. Gmail when used through IMAP). So, you're going to have to inline it anyway.

Comment: I actually only deal with outlook which does support the style block. But I guess inline is still the only option...